# angular-cli with VSTS- how to export unit test results in xml format?

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular-cli, azure-pipelines

I have an application developed with angular-cli. As part of the build process, we run the Unit tests and display the results in VSTS.

How can i generate unit test results in xml format so that i can integrate it with VSTS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume `integrate it with VSTS`  means using publish test result task to publish your unit test result to VSTS. You could use [karma-junit-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-junit-reporter)

> *karma-junit-reporter*  is a plugin for Karma that will allow us to **get the test output in an XML format** so that VSTS can present it for us nicely.

By default, VSTS is able to process JavaScript unit tests in the JUnit format. Karma has a JUnit reporter that can be installed:

```
npm install karma-junit-reporter --save-dev
```

This can be added to the Karma config file. Now you can run tests using the `--reporters=junit` flag and the test run will generate a file named `TESTS-browser_(platform).xml`.

For example, a local run on Windows 10 creates `TESTS-Chrome_54.0.2840_(Windows_10_0.0.0).xml`. If you open the file, you’ll see XML that defines the various test cases, how long they ran, and even a structure that holds the console output.

Besides suggest you use **PhantomJS**  a so called Headless Browser for your browser. A headless browser is a browser that is just running in the background, that you can only interact with via code or a terminal.

Finally use `ng test` command to perform the tests and publish test results:

[image]

For more detail info you could take a look at below wonderful blog:

- [Automated Angular Unit Testing on Visual Studio Team Services](https://medium.com/@flu.lund/automated-angular-unit-testing-on-visual-studio-team-services-22c03497265c)
- [Integrating Angular 2 Unit Tests with Visual Studio Team Services](https://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2016/12/integrating-angular-2-unit-tests-with.html)